# Linker command failed with exit code 1 - old version of ios application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I dont wanna duplikate any question but honestly i tried a tons of solution but any of them worked for me.

I have to update old application from 2013 written in ObjC (Xcode 3.* i think) but i cant even build version that should be able to build. I have xcode 8.3 should i download older one ?

**Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

ld: library not found for -lcrypto
[image: Build report]

[image: Build Settings]

I will appreciate everything.

Comment: remove `-Icypto` and add `$(inherited)`

Comment: sometimes its because of header search Path and you have to use $(inherited) but sometimes this error happens because of pod mailfunction. so if you are using "Icypto" in your pod file you can use pod update

Comment: @ami - i removed -lcrypto and added  $(inherited). Then itl complained about -lssl so i removed it either. Then it complained about -lsqlcipher and i removed it as well. Surprisingly it said the same thing that "library not found for -lcrypto"

Comment: @roozbehmo cocoapods are not used in this project

Comment: so if you have the source files add them again to your project then find the Path of the library and check for any difference in header and library search path with the files actual path. hope it works

Comment: which file did you use in your project??

Comment: @amirt can you specify what do you mean ? because in project are used all of the files

Comment: i mean cocoapods

Comment: @amirt i am not using cocoapods. Libraries were added manualy

Comment: i cant tell how i fixed it ... i just remove and add again all the libraries... Every route is same everything is same but on the 10th try of remove and add it worked :) maybe its because old code and some cache bug i realy cant tell